# Why am I getting an Object Required error on my Range variable

Tags: excel, vba, object

I can't figure this out. I have a `Range` variable `report_end` that I use throughout this sub. The first line that calls this variable works, but then the next line gives the error `Object Required`. The line in questions is:

`report_end.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"`

Here is a snippet:

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim report_end As Range
    Set report_end = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown)
    
    Range(report_end, report_end.Offset(-3, -2)).Delete
    
    report_end.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

End sub
```

Comment: You deleted the range that `report_end` referred to

Comment: To get a solution, you could explain what you're trying to achieve here, best by using a practical example, e.g.: I have data in the first 10 rows. I want to `Delete` (`Clear`, `ClearContents`) the range `F7:H10` and write a formula into cell `F8` (currently `H11`).

Comment: The line `Range(report_end, report_end.Offset(-3, -2)).Delete` also deletes the range `report_end ` and therefore `report_end`  is gone in the line `report_end.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"` and you can't use it anymore. Maybe you want to use `Range(report_end, report_end.Offset(-3, -2).ClearContents` instead which clears the contents but does not remove the object.

Comment: That's interesting. I was thinking that each time I called the `report_end` variable it would look at cell H1 and go to the end of the data block, where ever that may be when the variable is called. But you're saying that when I set the `Range` variable it won't be dynamic? Or does using `report_end.Delete` actually delete the variable altogether?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, you're deleting `report_end` and therefore, cannot access it afterwards.

Try setting the cell in the next row to `report_end`

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim report_end As Range
    Set report_end = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    
    With report_end.Offset(-1, 0)
        Range(.Cells, .Offset(-3, -2)).Delete
    End With

    report_end.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't work for me, I get an `Application defined or Object defined Error` on the line `Set report_end = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`